# Learning tranditional touch typing - is it worth the effort?

Tags: touch-typing

I have been programming for about 10 years now, but I never learned to touch type by the traditional method (with index fingers on 'f' and 'j').

I now 'touch type' in the sense that I rarely look at the keyboard, however I used mostly my index fingers.

I am wondering if anyone else has been in the same position and has decided to learn to touch type properly and how much effort they had to put in to break their old habits?

Also I can imagine that learning to type words probably comes quite quickly but all of the punctuation in programming might take **a lot** more practice?

Comment: **Yes**, yes, a thousand times yes, it's worth it, though it may take weeks of practice for you to start noticing the benefit, especially as you'll need to unlearn years of muscle memory.

Comment: I recommend a typing game to make the experience fun instead of work. *TyperShark* and *Typing of the Dead* are particularly good ones.

Comment: What is the definitive and correct answer to this question?  And remember, if you say that there isn't one, you are admitting that you probably didn't read the FAQ, and you didn't know the question isn't appropriate for SU.

Comment: I guess this would rather be a question for [chat] to poll for opinions and such.

Comment: @BonGart thanks for your non-constructive comment - it's nice that you have the time to make pointless comments on SU, I certainly don't have time for such things!

Comment: @BonGart - That's not really constructive and is entirely unnecessary.  Please don't bite new users.

Comment: Well, he was just pointing out *why* this question was closed. I don't see how this is entirely not constructive. The wording, maybe, but it raises the (good) point that there's no correct answer here. Regardless, let's not drift into an argument here.

Comment: @Shinrai how is what I said not constructive?  Please enlighten me.  I pointed out that one should read the FAQ, I pointed out that the question wasn't a good fit (And you friggin agreed by voting to close it), and I pointed out Exactly WHY it wasn't a good fit and why it would be closed?  I'd say that is FAR more constructive than your asinine comment to me and your silent pack vote to close.

Comment: @slhck "drift"?  His comment doesn't drift, it purposefully steers it that way.  I shouldn't be surprised though... hell, the question even got upvotes.

Comment: @BonGart - I thought your comment came across as incredibly confrontational and hostile.  (Apparently so did OP) This question is not a good one, but that's no reason to be mean about it.  Just choose your words more carefully. :)

Comment: I think there is an answer for this if one could demonstrate how the development of the "QWERTY" keyboard and Amos Densmores' study on key-pairs (placings of "th" and "er/re" for example) are a factor. I think the widely used QWERTY keyboard (initially for typewriters) is significant in why one would "touch type".

Comment: What if you use a Dvorak keyboard then? The research for the development of the QWERTY keyboard wouldn't have much bearing. Whether or not touch typing is worth the effort of learning is completely a personal preference. Personally I believe it is, but that is still just my personal opinion.

Comment: Just did a google of "Touch Type Training" theres loads of sites. Check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to say that the best thing I ever learn't was touch typing. My WPM went up, My wrist strain was reduced and accuracy is also increased. It depends how stuck in your ways your are, 10 years... Its not going to be easy.

Answer (score 5):

Touch typing not only increases your typing speed, it decreases the time you have to think about typing. You say you "rarely" look at the keyboard, but those times you are still somewhat distracted from your train of thought.

While typing this, I don't need to look at the keys, and never thought about how to place my fingers or anything. In fact while typing (without 'breaking stride') I looked up at the wording you used in your post (about "rarely" looking at the keyboard).

So my answer would be **yes**, it is definitely worth it.